# Problem with downloading NLTK packages with Google Cloud Build and Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, nltk, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud Run with Cloud Build where I want continuous deployment from Git. I am using a Docker file to build the image with Google Cloud Buildpack as I have to download Textblob Corpora  [(see topic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471754/is-there-a-way-to-download-textblob-corpora-to-google-cloud-run).

All the other parts of the app where I don't use Textblob works. When I make a container with Docker for testing locally (on my pc) and run, then it works all fine.

My Docker file is:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Build dependencies that you require for your pip installs
# Install production dependencies
# Remove packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-dev python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt \
    && python -m textblob.download_corpora \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc python3-dev python3-pip 

# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 2 --threads 8 --timeout 0 index:server
```

I have tried the following without succes:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc pytho3n-dev python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt \
    && python -m textblob.download_corpora -d /usr/share/nltk_data \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc python-dev python3-pip
```

and

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-dev python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt \
    && python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data movie_reviews \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc python-dev python3-pip
```

How can I fix this?

Best,

Vijay

**EDIT:**
It seems that Cloud Build downloads to the root directory

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package movie_reviews to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/movie_reviews.zip.
```

But the app in Cloud Run is looking for it in the home directory:

```
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040268Z Searched in:
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040277Z - '/home/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040287Z - '/usr/local/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040297Z - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040308Z - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040317Z - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040326Z - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040334Z - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
Default
2021-05-19T10:06:02.040343Z - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

Using `python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data movie_reviews` didn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to `apt-get install python`. There is already a Python in this image. Because you are installing Python, you need up with two Python installs which conflict and confuse what's going on.

So start by removing the `apt-get install python-dev python3-pip` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thanks Itamar,
But removing this will only give an exit error code. Then it doesn't install at all. It seems the problem is that there is a difference in the directory. While building it downloads to root and during the lookup in the app  it looks at home.

Comment: There may be an additional error, but you really do not want to install that second Python.

Comment: I have found my solution, I had to add ENV NLTK_DATA /nltk_data/
ADD . $NLTK_DATA to the Dockerfile, now it is working.